# asp.net mvc 3 access DateTime model property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In Asp.Net MVC I have a model containing a property of type `DateTime`.

How can I access it in JavaScript?

Using `@(Model.PrimitiveTypeProperty)` works just fine, but not when it comes to a property of `DateTime`.

The problem is more complex, but I need to at least have an alter with this value.
Is it possible?

Comment: Are you just looking to display the date/time using JavaScript or do you need it as a javascript `Date` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to basically translate your `DateTime` property to a JS `Date`, you could try something like:

```
var jsDate = Date.parse('@Model.EndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r")');
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly want I intended...didn't work exactly like that, but it help to get it:  `var jsDate = new Date(parseInt(@(Model.EndDate.Year)), parseInt(@(Model.EndDate.Month)), parseInt(@(Model.EndDate.Day)));`

Comment: @SandraS. yeah the example I gave wasn't correct as `Date` in JS expects an epoch timestamp (which `DateTime.Milliseconds` wouldn't give). I have updated my answer with something less verbose than the one you are using. Also, with your one you will lose any time information associated with the date.

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in a hidden for example:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YourDate)
```

And then access it from javascript.
After you modify it's value, on submit, you should get the value updated back to your controller.

And don't forget to put in in a form like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Comment: how do you modify it?  I'm having trouble reading the data from it.

Answer (score 2):

From your model you should have the DateTime property.

```
public class YourModel {

   public DateTime YourDateField { get; set; }

}
```

Then in your`View` you could do:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.YourDateField);
```

Accessing it using `JavaScript/jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var d = $("#YourDateField").val(); 
   alert(d);

  $("#YourDateField").val = "01/01/2000"; // sets the date which will then be posted back to the model on the form submit. 
});
```

This will alert the date value from your model.

```
 $("#YourDateField").val = "01/01/2000";
```

Changes the date client side.  If yor View has a `Form` element, when it is submitted back to the server the value passed back will reflect the change (01/01/2000).